# Windows authentication with ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: asp.net, iis, ldap, windows-authentication

I have an issue with my website authentication.

I'm building an website that needs to use the same single sign on as an intranet site.

My idea was to use windows authentication on the website to get the user credentials and then use LDAP to authenticate them against our client's Domain controller.
The website in question is hosted on a server outside the client's domain.
I've tried using the **ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider** but i cannot get it to work with integrated authentication.

My issue is that my i cannot get windows authentication to use LDAP as a membership provider. At the moment, windows authentication gets the user credentials, tries to authenticate them against users on the computer and fails as the web server is not on the domain. I want to get the credentials and send them using LDAP to a domain controller that will authenticate them.

Is there a way i can do integrated authentication using and LDAP connection for authentication?

Comment: When you are running Solution Local , Is it working fine with Windows Authentication?

Comment: Yeah, windows authentication on the intranet works fine. The issue isn't getting the windows authentication to work, it's getting the windows authentication to validate it's credentials using the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider and a specified LDAP server rather than just going off and checking against its standard user list.

Comment: What is the issue den?...Do you want to know how you can communicate with Active Directory Server using LDAP Connection?

Comment: Yeah, i've set the active directory membership provider as the default membership provider, i've put in the address of our servers. Yet no data is sent to the domain controller of any sort.

Comment: Your Machine on which you are testing should must be on your domain to which AD you are communicating..I have also provided the Answer how can you Make connection using PrincipalContext

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated**

If your website is **Hosted** on the Server outside the Client's Domain then you can not get the User Authenticated.

Because when you send the Credential to the Hosted Server there is a **Location** object in the Domain Server, and it will try to find that specified **User**  first locally where you have hosted your website and then to the **Doamin Server** that have been specified in location(though we can also set the priority)

If it doesn't found any user locally then

After that it will Send request to the **Domain Server** with those **Credentials**.

In your case First it will not found that **Domain Server name** in the location object to which you want it to communicate with.

For ex:

```
 PrincipalContext pr = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "corp.local", "dc=corp,dc=local", username, password);
```

Here **Corp.Local** is the Domain name which is in my **Location object** and **Username and Password** of that user which have administrative rights for Edit/Update/Delete any user in Domain server.

So the whole process goes again and when the specified **Domain Server** is found in the Location object then it will make communication with that **Domain** and generate a **TOKEN**

The Only Solution for your case is that you need to replicate all your user  from Client Server to your Domain Server or else you need to make TRUST between two domain servers.

Hope this is what you are looking for.!!

Comment: in order to get the user.identity.name, don't the users need to have already authenticated?

Comment: @zeocrash That depends actually. In my case my user was already Logged in the Domain and What I am checking here whether that Domain ID is Enable or Exist in our Active Directory Server or not. Please Mention your code here or the error you are getting.

Comment: My issue is that my i cannot get windows authentication to use LDAP as a membership provider. At the moment, windows authentication gets the user credentials, tries to authenticate them and fails as the web server is not on the domain. I want to get the credentials and send them using LDAP to a domain controller that will authenticate them.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it wasn't possible. I didn't come up with the idea, i was just the unfortunate person tasked with building it. In the end our client were fine without single sign on, we just authenticate the username and password typed into a form with the LDAP code you provided.